# ListView does not refresh its items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I have a `ListView` where:

```
public class RowData
{
    public string Box1 { get; set; }
    public string Box2 { get; set; }
    public string Box3 { get; set; }
};

private ObservableCollection<RowData> Data = new ObservableCollection<RowData>();

...

MyListView.ItemsSource = Data;
```

I binded the properties of `RowData` with the `DisplayMemberBinding` property of my columns, for example:

```
MyGridViewColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Box1"));
```

I handle the `ListViewItem.DoubleClick` event:

```
private void ListViewItem_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = sender as ListViewItem;
    RowData data = item.DataContext as RowData;
    data.Box1 = "new string";
}
```

But when I assign the new string to my data the ListView does not refresh its items (I can still see the old value of `Box1`, even if `Box1` has a new value - a new double click shows that `Box1 == "new string"` before assigning the new string).

 Why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This post might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680653/getting-a-wpf-listview-to-display-observablecollectiont-using-databinding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

After you updated any property in your data class you need to inform View to update itself.

```
public class RowData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string box1;
    public string Box1 
    {
        get { return box1; }
        set
        {
            if(box1 == value) return;
            box1= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Box1 ");
        }
    }
 //repete the same to Box2 and Box3

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
 {
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
 }
 }
```